# Why is glTexImage2D returning GL_INVALID_OPERATION on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I'm making the following call on iOS using OpenGL ES 3:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,         // target
             0,                     // level
             GL_RGBA,               // internalformat
             1024,                  // width
             692,                   // height
             0,                     // border
             GL_RGBA,               // format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,      // type
             NULL);                 // data
```

However, it is returning `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. There are a [slew of reasons](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml#errors) that `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` might be returned. However, I can't spot any that are relevant to my situation.

The weird thing is if I just ignore the error, things seem to work anyway. However, I'd like to understand what's going on here because I don't want it to bite me later.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting an error here and how to avoid it?

Comment: I sometimes have this issue when I am using `GL_RGBA` instead of `GL_RGB`.

Comment: Try using KHR_debug extension if it's available - you'll get a better error reason on most drivers.

Comment: @solidpixel I can't find any info on `KHR_debug` for iOS - I can only assume it's not available. @indexoutofbounds I tried changing to `GL_RGBA` and get the same problem.